# Cakephp Self Dependency and getting dependency details

Tags: model, associations, cakephp-2.0

I have the below table structure. and I would like , when I give a find query on MenuRowSelection, to get the name from 'menu row'  of id and menu_row_selection_id. Instead on getting only one details for menu_row_selection_id, I am getting more than one details. Could someone please shed some light on this

### menu_row_selections

id,
menu_row_id,
menu_row_selection_id

### menu_rows

id,
name

Comment: please show what did you try so far

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted above, the solution depends on the association you have specified between these two models. Have you specified any such associations?

Also, it's unclear what exactly we are trying to find(Are we trying to retrieve based on some condition?).